# JOGL/OpenGL: "\n" (newline) does not working for text rendering

Tags: opengl, newline, glut, jogl

I have this function to render a text on my canvas:

```java
public void renderString(String s, int x, int y){
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrtho(0,WIDTH,0,HEIGHT,-1, 1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(x,y,0);
            gl.glScalef(textScalingFactor, textScalingFactor, 1f);
            glut.glutStrokeString(GLUT.STROKE_ROMAN, s);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

The problem is, newline character (\n) is not working and all of the following strings:

```java
String s1 = "bla"+"\n"+"bla";
String s2 = "bla\nbla";

char newLine = new char(10);
String s3 = "bla"+newLine+"bla";
```

are rendered like:

> blabla

Any ideas?

P.S. Tab (\t) is not working as well.

P.P.S. The same problem with glutBitmapString, glutBitmapCharacter, glutStrokeCharacter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is [just not implemented](http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl.git;a=blob;f=src/jogl/classes/com/jogamp/opengl/util/gl2/GLUT.java;h=010ce669918e45e3ccc138d53f9f8461c74e9426;hb=HEAD) (*given that your example runs this code...*) The translation always shifts `x`, never `y`. I shortened the following code a bit.

```
public void glutStrokeString(int font, String string) {
    /* setup */
    for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
        /* single char setup */
        StrokeCharRec ch = fontinfo.ch[c];
        if (ch != null) {            
            /* draw strokes */
        }
        gl.glTranslatef(ch.right, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

It's very likely that the other methods share the same issue.

Anyway, you could split the string yourself, drawing each part with an increasing `y` shift, and replacing `\t` by some extra `x` offset.